# RequireJS Callback parameter function Mapping for dependencies array

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I noted the following code in RequireJS;

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'ojs/ojprogressbar', 'ojs/ojtree'],        
function(oj)
{
 return oj;
});
```

Now I thought that the callback function mapping for dependencies array has to match one-to-one.

However, in the above code, there are 3 array dependencies, but just one parameter specified in the callback function.

Is the code still valid? How does the mapping happen? Is it as per normal Javascript bheavior or RequireJS specific ?

Comment: Have a look at `define()` to find out how its args are used.

Answer (score 0):

Out of context there is nothing unusual in the code you show. For instance, the last 2 modules could be registering with the first one somehow and don't actually return a module value. That's completely fine. The function will be called with 3 arguments but only the first one will be bound to a variable name (`oj`). That's normal JavaScript behavior, not specific to RequireJS. For instance, you can do:

```
function foo(bar) {
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

And `bar` will get the value `1` when `foo` is called. `2` and `3` will also be passed but not bound to any variable. You could still access them by using the automatic [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) variable.

A classic example of modules that don't normally return values is jQuery plugins. For instance you could have:

```
define(['jquery', 'pluginA', 'pluginB'], function ($) {
    $('#whatever').pluginA(....);
    $('#somethingelse').pluginB(....);
});
```

This is completely common. The plugins register with the `jQuery` (or `$`) object itself and their modules return an `undefined` value.